# Using Tow Properties Section in ApplicationSetting SectionGroup Web.Config

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-config, app-config

I have added a reference to a WCF my Service that this library has an app.config.
in the app.config there is a `applicationSettings` sectionGroup and there is 'Properties' section

When I add a Properties Section into web.config it doesn't work:

My proprties section in app.config is

```
<IranTcDriver.Properties.Settings>
    <setting name="IranTcDriver_tc_iran_ws_SMS_WebServer_Service" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://wwww.wwww.www/index.php</value>
    </setting>
    <setting name="UserName" serializeAs="String">
        <value>tavanm-----</value>
    </setting>
    <setting name="Password" serializeAs="String">
        <value>-------------</value>
    </setting>
</IranTcDriver.Properties.Settings>
```

and then
I add below tag is `<applicationSettings>` section group and add

```
<section name="IranTcDriver.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false">
```

When I add this tags in web.config I get Error about multiple properties section.
any one can help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this setting in configuration file (web.config)
in applicationSettings sectionGroup add `IranTcDriver.Properties.Settings`

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <section name="IranTcDriver.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

Then in `<applicationSettings>` in web.config add

```
<IranTcDriver.Properties.Settings>
    <setting name="IranTcDriver_tc_iran_ws_SMS_WebServer_Service" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://wwww.wwww.www/index.php</value>
    </setting>
    <setting name="UserName" serializeAs="String">
        <value>tavanm-----</value>
    </setting>
    <setting name="Password" serializeAs="String">
        <value>-------------</value>
    </setting>
</IranTcDriver.Properties.Settings>
```

this should be work